# This PDO statement is returning an integer instead of a string

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

In a class, I have some PDO:

```
$userFName = 'userFName';
include('dbconnect.php');       // Normally I'd store the db connect script outside of webroot
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;", $db_user, $db_password);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT userFName FROM Users WHERE username = :uname AND password = :pword AND roleID = 1');
$stmt->bindParam(':uname', $this->user->username);
$stmt->bindParam(':pword', $this->user->password);
$stmt->bindColumn(4, $userFName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$familiar = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);
$this->user->firstName = $familiar;
```

It's returning the ID in the first column instead of the VARCHAR contents in the 4th column. Any idea why?

Comment: As I only see 1 column in your resultset I'm surprised you get _anything at all_? And aren't you just setting `$this->user->firstName` to `true` (the result of `FETCH_BOUND`), and see that as in 1 when cast to string or int?

Comment: It looks like you are selecting one column and binding to a (non-existant) fourth column. Shouldn't it be `$stmt->bindColumn(1, $userFName, PDO::PARAM_STR);`?

Comment: I had SELECT * and it did the same thing.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought the first param of bindColumn() was the place of the column in the table

Comment: So... use `1` for the column, and use `$this->user->firstName=$userFName;`, not `$this->user->firstName = $theResultOfYourExecute;`...

Comment: @Wrikken what should I be fetching then? I don't want an array or anything.

Comment: @MonicaRice: your fetch is fine. But you _bound_ the variable, so other then to check whether the result of your `fetch()` is `true`, there's no data from the resultset in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `PDO::FETCH_BOUND` with `fetch()`, the method will not return a result record. Instead the value of the column should be available in the variable you have bound using `$stmt->bindColumn()` earlier.

So change your code to:

```
$stmt->bindColumn(1, $userFName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);
$this->user->firstName = $userFName; // <-- use the bound variable
```

---

However you won't need that `bindColumn()` call. You could simplify the code as this:

```
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(); // uses PDO::FETCH_ASSOC by default
$this->user->firstName = $row['FName'];
```

Comment: Looks cool, but should be column 1 rather than 4. Alternatively, use the column name.

Comment: I see now, this was another error in the question's code. Have replaced `4` by `1`. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Thanks for including a alternate (shorter) method, too. Nice touch.

Answer (score 0):

There is too much code in your class. And one fault. To send a **distinct query** to get just one property from database, creating a **distinct connection** for this is a **dead overkill.**
Connection have to be moved away unconditionally and you must think of getting ALL user data with **one** query.

Proper code

```
function __construct($pdo) {
    $this->pdo = $pdo;
    // Normally you should include somewhere in a bootstrap file
    // not in the application class
    // and instantiate PDO in that bootstrap as well
    // and only PASS already created instance to the class
}

function getUserFName() {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = ? AND password = ? AND roleID = 1';
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($this->user->username,$this->user->password));
    return $stmt->fetchColumn();
}
```

Comment: Have you read the question? What is the advantage of your answer?